# Understanding jQuery's jqXHR

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of `$.get()` requests that I need to refactor to include a failure callback.  The requests are of the form

```
$.get(url,
      {},
      function(data) {//success, do work
      //work
      },'json');//or 'html'
```

According to the jQuery API, I simply add a jqHXR object.  So in my case, I believe I should do

```
var jqxhr =  $.get(url,
          {},
          function(data) {//success, do work
          //work
          },'json').error(function() { alert("error"); });//or 'html'
```

I don't understand the reason for the second success callback in [the example](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).  I suppose it could be there for setting up a callback chain.  I want error to execute in error, and success to execute on success.  So, is this correct?

Comment: Which example on the page? Sorry, I couldn't locate what you're referring to.

Comment: looks like the 3rd code sample.

Comment: When you hit the page look for the section titled 'The jqXHR Object'.  The example directly below that title is the one I am referring to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the second success callback in the example is just there to illustrate that, using this syntax, you can have multiple handlers for `success`, `error`, and `complete` events. In the standard jQuery `.ajax()` method, you can only assign a single handler to each of these events. I can't think offhand of an example that would *require* multiple handlers, but it does seem a little clearer and more like the standard jQuery idiom to use

```
$.get('my_url.php')
    .success(handlerOne)
    .success(handlerTwo);
```

instead of

```
$.get('my_url.php', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    handlerOne(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    handlerTwo(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
});
```

In your case, though, it might be easier and cleaner to just convert your `$.get()` statements to `$.ajax()`. The `$.ajax()` syntax is probably more familiar to most jQuery programmers, and since you don't need the special functionality (multiple handlers, post-request handler assignment) available in the other syntax, there's no reason not to just use `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        // success, do work
    },
    error: function(data) {
        // error, handle failure
    },
    dataType:'json'
});
```

Comment: I agree, the second option makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I find clear-cut explanations like yours tends to be rare. API documentation and official sites tend to get into extreme detail about everything, which has its place, but they don't emphasize the practicality, or recommended options as clearly. They also tend to give abstractions without examples that cover enough ground.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this answer: "Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead." (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 4):

This page has a lot of documentation on how jqXHR (jQuery XHR) differs from XHR (XMLHttpRequest).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 2):

The code you are using should be fine. The second success is just another place where you can define a success method. Some people use the `jqxhr` success instead of the one passed into `$.get()`, and others use the deferred object's done handler to do the same.

Comment: the multiple ways of doing things in javascript, and the implicit silence on alternative syntax is the most confusing part of learning js for me.

Comment: @gwho the best solution to that is to go to the source. Often times the documentation simply isn't enough

Comment: I find the source is even more confusing due to the meta programming, and for the same reason the API explanations are confusing. I think good clear examples that strip away the details, and leave you with the core important and most common aspects is the most easily absorbed way of conveying information. That's just my take. I find if you can read the source, you're already good enough not to be confused about multiple syntax.

Comment: @ahnbizcad This is a good explanation of jXHR: https://www.sitepoint.com/jqxhr-object/