# Check whether all rest requests got response or not in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want a callback function which will get called after all rest requests got response from server in backbone js.
Function will execute after only all requests got response, not for each response.

I know about success, error, and complete methods but, these methods are executes for each response.

Please tell me about any other functions are present or get called after all response received from server.

I posted code below to fetch data from server.

```
fetchNextPage : function( successCallback, errorCallback, completeCallback, context )
    {
        this.requestNextPage({
            remove : false,
            success : function( collection, response, options ) {
                if ( typeof successCallback === "function" )
                {
                    successCallback.apply( context, [ collection, response, options ]);
                }
            },

            error : function( collection, response, options ) {
                if ( typeof errorCallback === "function" )
                {
                        errorCallback.apply( context, [ collection, response, options ]);
                }
            },

            complete: function( xhr, status ){
                if ( typeof completeCallback === "function" )
                {
                        completeCallback.apply( context, [ xhr, status ]);
                }  
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the jQuery `$.when()` function.

> jQuery.when( deferreds )
>
> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more
>   objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

Each jQuery AJAX request will return an [jqXHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638847/understanding-jquerys-jqxhr) object which is a part of [jQuery's implementation](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) of [promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). The jqXHR object is returned synchronously, and then triggers again when the asynchronous operation it represents completes. You can then set a listener/callback on one (or more) of those promises with [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). The value returned by the asynchronous operation will be passed into the callback wrapped by `then`.

```
$.when(jqXHR1, jqXHR2, jqXHR3).then(function(return1, return2, return3) {
    //callback here will run only after the requests that returned the 
    //asyncronous operations linked to jqXHR 1-3 are completed.
});
```